# ld warning: file A.o: attempted multiple inclusion of file

Tags: c++, unix, solaris, ld

I am trying to port some windows C++ code to Solaris (Unix). I am compiling the code using  CC(the SUN C++ compiler). After some efforts, I only have one warning message left as shown below.

```
ld: warning: file A.o: attempted multiple inclusion of file
```

I try to search the warning message. But what I got are some info that this warning can be ignored... Although it is a warning, I would really like to understand it and solve it.

May I know if any one can give me some clue what this warning means?

Thanks,

Comment: What does your `Makefile` look like? I'm guessing you've referenced that file multiple times when linking the final executable...

Comment: Either that or the command make ran which generated the error

Comment: Yup, you are right. Very stupid mistake. I compile the cpp twice in the makefile. Could you place your comment as answer? I will mark it solved. Thank you very much.